# What is the biblical basis for the doctrine that salvation cannot be lost?

Tags: biblical-basis, soteriology, perseverance-of-saints

Not much to add to the title. How do Christians who advocate the "once saved, always saved" doctrine back it up with Scripture? How do they commonly defend their interpretations against rebuttals from critics?